# for loop through 5 textboxes

Tags: powershell, administrator

I have created a GUI with 5 Textboxes. I call them $textboxHost1 - 5.
Now I have an array in which I'm gonna save up to 5 values and then write each value according to the order into the textboxes. The first value in the array should be written into the first $textboxHost1 box.

To do that, I would like to make a for loop and have written this code

```
#$hostnameneingabe: Array, in which the values are saved.
$hostnameneingabeCount = $hostnameneingabe.Count
for($i = 0; $i -le $hostnameneingabeCount; $i++) {
    #code here
}
```

Now, I'm looking for a way to go down the order, so that the first $textboxHost1 comes firstly and so on.

To be accurate, the variable $textboxHost should be incrementally increased in the loop and the values at the position $i in the array should be written into that textbox.
sth like

```
for($i = 0; $i -le $hostnameneingabeCount; $i++) {
    $textboxHost$i = 
}
```

Comment: does this help: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/basics-of-powershell-looping-foreach/

Comment: no bro, it is not what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you would be liking something like this?

```
$textboxHosts = Get-Variable | ? {$_.Name -match "textBoxHost[0-9]" -and $_.Value -ne $null} | sort Name
```

After this you can process that var with eg. a foreach:

```
foreach ($textboxHost in $textboxHosts) {<# Do some stuff #>}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an array, because otherwise you can't loop through them:

```
$textboxHost = @(0..4)
#Textbox 0
$textboxHost[0] = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textboxHost[0].Text = "test"

#Textbox 1
$textboxHost[1] = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textboxHost[1].Text = "test"

foreach ($textbox in $textboxHost){
    #Do whatever you want with the textbox
    $textbox = 
}
```